# Holographic Material - Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How would I create the following in Cycles:

Holographic Material - [Video](http://www.cinema4dtutorial.net/?p=1804)

In Blender there is no Mograph Alternative so not sure how to build the spatial animating sphere effect. Hopefully no volumetric or missing special shader nodes will be needed. The flashing effect is done by animating the displacement. How would I approach that in cycles?

I included plenty of sample so you get an idea of what I am going for.

P.S So gave it a thought. Since some of the materials seem similar to the other question I asked. Could particles be used instead of MoGraph and hide the base mesh afterwards to make the holographic objects? What about the atom arrays with connected lines?

Thank You

[image: I1]
[image: I2]
[image: I3]
[image: I4]

Comment: Seems more like a tutorial request

Comment: Uhm...All questions on this site are tutorial requests if you want it that way. Everyone who ask a question wants a tut on how he should solve an issue or make something.

Comment: Please see: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6 and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

Comment: @00Ghz, you are much more likely to get satisfying answers if you do your own experiments and feel that you've hit a roadblock, that's when to seek advice. Incidentally there is content on the [Tears of Steal DVD](http://mango.blender.org/production/dvd-box-contents/) which will cover similar visual effects.

Comment: The last comment is definitely useful. Thanks.